# Django's Wagtail images have faulty S3 URL

Tags: django, amazon-s3, wagtail

I'm trying to upload images to my Django site's S3 storage using Wagtail. The images upload properly, but Wagtail appends `?AWSAccessKeyId=` followed by a bunch of gibberish to the image URL.

This causes the image to fail to load in both Wagtail's admin as well as the actual site.

If I remove the appended text then the URL works properly. The problem is, I don't know how to stop Wagtail from appending the text in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/stable/backends/amazon-S3.html#settings) docs, you can set `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH` to False to disable the query parameter.